# Expect with SJWS wadm command

Tags: bash, expect

I'm using expect in the very traditional way of match string, send desired inputs within a bash script wrapping around iplanet/SJWS wadm command, which itself is a bash script calling a java program.

Rather than when I run the program manually, certain components such as passwords get echoed back to the shell and the control characters don't seem to be sent.

I think it might be a multiline regexp issue, but using a wildcard at the front of the expect doesn't seem to work, and using the debug option (when sending a password string) has the expect comparing the password with the string I want to match it to.

I don't have much experience with expect and was hoping if anyone had seen this issue before.

Thanks

Comment: /usr/bin/expect < EOF
    spawn wadm reset-admin-password
    expect ".* enter admin-password>"
    send "$PASSWD\r\n"
    expect ".* enter admin-password again>"
    send "$PASSWD\r\n"
    EOF

As I said, very trivial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that:

- you are using Unix environment;
- you have no problems running an expect file, instead of expect one-liners;
- you run the following script from the path in which `wadm` script is found;

This will probably suit your needs:

**reset.exp**

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

if {$argc != 1} {
    puts "Usage: expect $argv0 password"
    exit 1
}
set PASSWD [lindex $argv 0] ;# get password from the first argument

spawn -noecho $env(SHELL) ;# spawn a new process, in order to use send/expect
set timeout 10     ;# short one (10 s)
log_user 0         ;# disable showing up sensitive info (PASSWD value)

set cmd "wadm reset-admin-password" ;# put the command string into a variable
send "$cmd\r"
expect {
    -regex "enter admin-password.*$" {
        puts "Got the password request ..."
    }
    timeout {
        puts "ERROR: Timeout reached during running $cmd !"
        exit 1
    }
}
send "$PASSWD\r"
expect {
    -regex "enter admin-password again.*$" {
        send "$PASSWD\r"
        expect -re ".*$"
        # TODO: define reject/accept patterns
        puts "Password accepted!"
    }
    timeout {
        puts "ERROR: Timeout reached on entering password!"
        exit 1
    }
}
send "exit\r"
expect eof
```

Comment: Cheers, Ill give it a go first thing!

Comment: Ok! let me know of the results!

Comment: I've rather hackily added to your code to detect the "Please enter admin-password again>" prompt, however I think some things are occuring out of order, using the debug and racking the logging up to 10 shows this - (sorry reply means I have to use a separate box

Comment: Password accepted!
Gate keeper glob pattern for '.*enter admin-password again.*$' is '*enter admin-password again*'. Activating booster.

expect: does "" (spawn_id exp4) match regular expression ".*enter admin-password again.*$"? Gate "*enter admin-password again*"? gate=no
password

expect: does "password\r\n" (spawn_id exp4) match regular expression ".*enter admin-password again.*$"? Gate "*enter admin-password again*"? gate=no

Comment: I've updated the example to match the "enter admin-password again" pattern.

Comment: Thanks, Ill give it a go, although I suspect Oracle are doing something silly with subshells :S

Comment: Still no luck, even with log level at 0, it still seems to detect the password being entered on the first line as a seperate entry, and then tries to match that with the next input, using the password passw0rd - 

expect: does "" (spawn_id exp4) match regular expression ".*Please enter admin-password again.*$"? Gate "*Please enter admin-password again*"? gate=no

expect: does "passw0rd\r\n" (spawn_id exp4) match regular expression ".*Please enter admin-password again.*$"? Gate "*Please enter admin-password again*"? gate=no

Answer (score 0):

And managed to get things resolved, the wadm command appears to make a soap connection that slows things down, so

```
/usr/bin/expect << EOD
set password $PASSWD
spawn $BINDIR/wadm reset-admin-password
sleep 1
expect -re ".*admin-password> " {send -- "$password\r"}
expect -re ".*admin-password again> " {send -- "$password\r"}
expect -re ".*CLI" {send -- "exit\r"}
interact
EOD
```

Thanks for the help!